# Android-AlertDialog - doesn't work

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Yesterday I had programmed a little AlertDialog with my Android-Phone via AIDE programmed. On the Internet I've found the source code

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this).create();
// Setting Dialog Title
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
// Setting Dialog Message
alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to AndroidHive.info");
// Setting Icon to Dialog
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);
// Setting OK Button
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
// Showing Alert Message
alertDialog.show();
```

I have tested this in AIDE and it's working, then I've tested it within AndroidStudio and it didn't work. Why does it work in AIDE and not in Android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                AlertDialogActivity.this);
```

Edit first line as above since you need to set builder before creating alertDialog

Complete code as follows:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                AlertDialogActivity.this);
// Setting Dialog Title
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

// Setting Dialog Message
alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to AndroidHive.info");

// Setting Icon to Dialog
alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

// Setting OK Button
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
AlertDialog alertDialogMain = alertDialog.create();

// Showing Alert Message
alertDialogMain.show();
```

Comment: ok i try, but i don't know why it work in AIDE and in Android studio not

Comment: ok i had test your code, an it isn't work. My code isn't not more

Comment: Can you paste the log

Comment: The code is working perfectly! Are you  trying it on real device?
Try to import
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; instead of import android.app.AlertDialog;

Comment: ok the import is it, i have use import android.app.AlertDialog; and they doesn't work, but when i'm use import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; it's work lol ...  why ? and yes i use a real device

Comment: AlertDialog was introduced in API11(Honeycomb) and to support lower versions always import support libraries.
You might be testing it on lower API.
Mark this as answer

Comment: i programmed for 19 to  + and not lower but is ok